# Plotly: How to include multiple text variables in plot?

Tags: python, plotly, bubble-chart

How can I show multiple text variables in an `iplot()`?
Here is an example:

```
df2007.iplot(kind='bubble', x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp', size='pop', text='country',
             xTitle='GDP per Capita', yTitle='Life Expectancy',
             filename='cufflinks/simple-bubble-chart')
```

taken from here: https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/#scatter-matrix

I want to add another variable to text, passing a list of column names doesn't help.
I have tried

```
text = 'country' + <br/> + 'country'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you'll have to free yourself from the boundaries of `px.Scatter`. But you can use `go.Scatter` in combination with `iplot()` if that is what you prefer. The snippet below will show you how you can assign an extra variable with it's own data in your hovertext by [formatting hovertemplate](https://plot.ly/python/hover-text-and-formatting/) correctly and using the `text` propery of `go.Scatter`.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# data
gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
df=gapminder.query("year==2007").copy(deep=True)
df['extraVar']=[i**4 for i in range(len(df))]

# plotly
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['gdpPercap'], y=df['lifeExp'],
                         mode='markers',
                         marker=dict(size=df['pop'],sizemode='area',
                                sizeref=2.*max(df['pop'])/(40.**2),sizemin=2
                                    ),
                         hovertemplate =
                                        '<i>lifeExp</i>: $%{y:.2f}'+
                                        '<br><i>gdpPercap</i>: %{x}<br>'+
                                        '<i>%{text}</i>',
                         text = ['Your extra variable {}'.format(i) for i in df['extraVar']],
                        )
             )

# iplot
iplot(fig)
```